# Change the style of the table of contents in appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, xetex, koma-script, tocloft

*This question was asked in the StackOverflow Russian segment, but was not answered. The question was translated automatically with some corrections, I hope I can get an answer to it here.*

I am doing my graduation thesis. At the end of the thesis, there should be appendixes that must be contained in a certain way, in contrast to the thesis itself, an approximate form:

```
Table of contents

1 Chapter name ......page
  1.1 Section name ......page
     1.1.1 Subsection name ......page
Appendix А ......page
Appendix B ......page
```

That is:

1. If the appendix has sections - they should not be displayed in toc
2. Appendix titles shouldn't show up either in toc

I tried to highlight the minimum working code that shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=14bp,a4paper]{scrreprt}

% Подключение пакетов
%===================================================
\usepackage{polyglossia}    %для русского языка
\usepackage[left=25mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, footskip=10mm]{geometry} %задаёт поля документа
\usepackage{tocloft} %пакет для оформления оглавления
\usepackage{titlesec} %пакет для оформления заголовков
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} %добавление списка источников в оглавление
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} %добавление приложений в оглавление

% Установка параметров для документа
%===================================================
\setdefaultlanguage[forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}  % устанавливает главный язык документа, опция - убирает последнюю точку в нумерации заголовков
\setotherlanguage{english} % объявляет второй язык документа
\pagestyle{plain} %номера страниц будут печататься снизу и при этом колонтитулов не будет
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}, Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
\parindent=1.25cm %красная строка

\renewcaptionname{russian}{\contentsname}{\normalsize \MakeUppercase{Содержание}} %заголовок оглавления
\renewcaptionname{russian}{\appendixname}{Приложение} %заголовок приложений
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % заполнение точками Глав в оглавлении

%параметры заголовков разделов (глав)
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thechapter~}{0pt}{\thispagestyle{empty}\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{\parindent}{0bp}{2\baselineskip}
%параметры заголовков подразделов (секций)
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection~}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{\parindent}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection~}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{\parindent}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        Титульный лист
    \end{titlepage}
    
    \tableofcontents{}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \clearpage
    
    \chapter{Первая}
        \section{Первый}
            \subsection{первый}
            
    \chapter{Вторая}
        \section{Второй}
            \subsection{второй}
            
    \begin{appendices}  
        \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\centering\appendixname~\thechapter}{0pt}{\centering\thispagestyle{empty}\MakeUppercase}
        \titlespacing{\chapter}{\parindent}{0bp}{\baselineskip}
        \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection~}{0pt}{}
        \titlespacing{\section}{0bp}{0bp}{\baselineskip}
        
        \chapter{Первое приложение}
            \section{Первый}
            
            \section{Второй}
            
            \section{Третий}
            
        \chapter{Второе приложение}
            \section{Первый}
            
            \section{Второй}
            
            \section{Третий}
    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

I found ~3 solutions to this issue, but none of them work:

1. Command `\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}` - the compiler throws an error (and a similar solution is to declare a separate command for this)
2. `tocvsec2` package with `\settocdepth{chapter}` command - just doesn't work, completely ignored

There are suspicions that there are some conflicts - therefore, none of the methods is not working. As for removing headings from the content, I also did not find any solution, but I suspect that it needs to be substituted in the `appendices` environment. I also searched in the documentation of the `tocloft` package, which I use.

Distribution: TeXLive

Compiler: XeLaTeX

Comment: the `scrreprt` class recommends not to user the `tocloft` package with the class. You should have got a warning about that when you compiled your MWE.

Comment: The actual formatting is done by \l@chapter, while the only way to change something in the middle of the TOC is using \addtocontents.  One solution is to have \l@chapter check a flag (see \newif) and have \addtocontents set the flag.

Comment: Initially, I used ```toсloft``` to fill with dots in the table of contents. I didn't find any other way to do this.

Comment: To get dots between chapter heading and page number in ToC, you can use either KOMA-option toc=chapterentrywithdots or \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill]{tocline}{chapter}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use packages `tocloft`, `titlesec`, `tocbibind` and `appendix` together with a KOMA-Script class.

Here is a suggestion without these packages:

```latex
\documentclass[
  fontsize=14bp,
  %a4paper,% default
  appendixprefix,% use prefix for appendix chapters
  numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}

\KOMAoption{toc}{%
  listof,% LoF and LoT etc. get unnumbered ToC entries
  bibliography,% bibliography gets unnumbered ToC entry
  index,% index gets unnumbered ToC entry
  chapterentrywithdots% dots between chapter heading and page number in ToC
}

% Подключение пакетов
%===================================================
\usepackage{polyglossia}    %для русского языка
\usepackage[left=25mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm, footskip=10mm]{geometry} %задаёт поля документа

% Установка параметров для документа
%===================================================
\setdefaultlanguage[forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}  % устанавливает главный язык документа, опция - убирает последнюю точку в нумерации заголовков
\setotherlanguage{english} % объявляет второй язык документа
\pagestyle{plain} %номера страниц будут печататься снизу и при этом колонтитулов не будет
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}, Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}

%\parindent=1.25cm %красная строка
\newlength{\myparindent}
\setlength{\myparindent}{1.25cm}
\setparsizes{\myparindent}{0pt}{0pt plus 1fil}

\renewcaptionname{russian}{\contentsname}{Содержание} %заголовок оглавления
\renewcaptionname{russian}{\appendixname}{Приложение} %заголовок приложений

%параметры заголовков разделов (глав)
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries,
  beforeskip=0bp,
  afterskip=2\baselineskip,
  innerskip=0bp
]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \@hangfrom{\hskip\myparindent #2}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
  #2\MakeUppercase{#3}%
}
\renewcommand{\chapterformat}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\ }\thechapter~}

%параметры заголовков подразделов (секций)
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  font=\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries,
  beforeskip=\baselineskip,
  afterskip=\baselineskip,
  indent=\myparindent,
  afterindent=false
]{section,subsection}
\renewcommand{\sectionformat}{\thesection~}
\renewcommand{\subsectionformat}{\thesubsection~}

\newcommand\originalappendix{}
\let\originalappendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \originalappendix
  \renewcommand{\raggedchapter}{\centering}%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=\baselineskip]{chapter}%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0bp,indent=0bp]{section}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\value{tocdepth}=\chaptertocdepth}% appendix sections etc. not shown in ToC
  \renewcommand\addchaptertocentry[2]{%
    \addtocentrydefault{chapter}{}{\appendixname~##1}%
  }% appendix titles not shown in ToC
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  Титульный лист
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Первая}
  \section{Первый}
    \subsection{первый}
\chapter{Вторая}
  \section{Второй}
    \subsection{второй}

\appendix
\chapter{Первое приложение}
  \section{Первый}
  \section{Второй}
  \section{Третий}
\chapter{Второе приложение}
  \section{Первый}
  \section{Второй}
  \section{Третий}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In this example it works. However, when I tried to implement this solution into my work, something went wrong and the document stopped compiling, the program gave a bunch of errors. It's a lot more complex than I expected, I'm afraid, but it's entirely my fault for not giving the full picture. I will sort this out. But the solution is still working.